# Twitter Follower Count using vertical box

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I'm trying to create a vertical box count for folowers using new API 1.1.

I found the below code that worked until some days ago. Now it doesn't work anymore.

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://twitter.com/users/user_name.json?callback=?',
    data: {
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#followers').html(data.followers_count);
       }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="twitter_box"><span id="followers"></span></div><a href="https://twitter.com/user_name" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name="false"></a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

CSS:

```
.twitter_box {
width: 58px; height: 34px;
position: relative;
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #bbb;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-ms-border-radius: 3px;
-o-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.twitter_box:after,
.twitter_box:before {
width: 0; height: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
border: solid transparent;
pointer-events: none;
content: " ";
}
.twitter_box:after {
left: 50%;
border-top-color: #fff;
border-width: 3px;
margin-left: -3px;
}
.twitter_box:before {
left: 50%;
border-top-color: #aaa;
border-width: 4px;
margin-left: -4px;
}
.twitter_box #followers {
width: 100%; height: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0px; left: 0px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px; line-height: 34px;
letter-spacing: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
color: #333;
text-align: center;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

As I said before it worked until 2 weeks ago.

Anyone can help me to found a workaround?

Thanks in adv,
Enrico

Comment: If it worked before and not now then it might not be your code as such, but the twitter URL you are using in your code that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace your code with this

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json',
data: {screen_name: 'your_username'},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
    $('#followers').html(data.followers_count);
   }
});
```